# $3$SAT generation with prescribed number of solutions

Tags: computational-complexity, sat

Given $n,k\in\Bbb N$ with $0\leq k \leq 2^n$ can we generate an uniformly random instance among all possible solutions of an $n$ variable $3$-SAT instance and exactly $k$ solutions in $poly(n\log k)$ time?

Is it possible to frame this as a decision and search problem without any lexicographic ordering of SAT instances?